# Is there a way to simplify this code using a loop?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop

Is there a way to simplify this code using a loop?

```
VariableList <- c(v0,v1,v2, ... etc)

National_DF <- df[,VariableList]
AL_DF <- AL[,VariableList]
AR_DF <- AR[,VariableList]
AZ_DF <- AZ[,VariableList]
... etc
```

I want the end result to have each as a data frame since it will be used later in the model. Each state such as 'AL', 'AR', 'AZ', etc are data frames. The v{#} represents an out of place variable from the RAW data frame. This is meant to restructure the fields, while eliminating some fields, for preparation for model use.

Comment: Please edit your post to  make a Minimal Reproducible Example.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269 .  You _must_ include some sample data; 4-10 lines is usually enough. Edit your post to include the results of `dput(head(df))`, if `df` is where your data is. Include a sample of what you want the output to look like.  Don't include images or  links to outside data source.  We want to help you, but you've got to work with us.

Comment: I can see this runing with sapply, but you have to provide an better exemple how you dada is strutured for ```v{#}```

Comment: Don't add `rstudio` tag if your question is not specifically about RStudio i.e the IDE.

Comment: Ronak, sorry...Still learning. Will try and be more aware moving forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing the answer from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62055654/3962914), we can arrange the data in the same `lapply` call before creating dataframes.

```
VariableList <- c('v0','v1','v2')

data <- unlist(lapply(mget(ls(pattern = '_DF$')), function(df) {
    index <- sample(1:nrow(df), 0.7*nrow(df))
    df <- df[, VariableList]
    list(train = df[index,], test = df[-index,])  
}), recursive = FALSE)
```

Then get data in global environment :

```
list2env(data, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Ronak, thanks again! I had to do some alterations to my prequel code but I was able to get this to simplify both questions based off you feedback. Thank!!!